# CRLF expected at end of chunk: -1/-1 with STS and ClearCase

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, ibm-rational

We use Spring Tool Suite 3.2 for our development, via Clearcase plugin in STS our folks create CCRC views.

Randomly we are getting CRLF expected at end of chunk: -1/-1, this is happening while downloading files.

Any idea ?

```
ClearCase server -> Windows 2003
Client -> Windows 7
CC Version  -> 7.1
```

Error

CRLF expected at end of chunk: -1/-1

Answer (score 1):

You can check with your admin how the default [text mode](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_tmode.htm) has been set for the views managemed by the  CCRC server: see "[Setting a default view text mode](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_ccrc_config_tmode.htm)".

Maybe that setting has an influence on the update part of the web views (which are snapshot views in CCRC)

Comment: Below are the errors I see in -> 12/09/14 15:00:36:307 BST] 00000028 CMLogger      E   CRVSV0133E I/O error
[12/09/14 15:00:36:307 BST] 00000028 CMLogger      E   CRVSV0571I Exception reason code: write-failed 
[12/09/14 15:00:36:307 BST] 00000028 CMLogger      E   CRVSV0133E I/O error
[12/09/14 15:00:36:322 BST] 00000028 CMLogger      E   CRVSV0960I Caused by:
[12/09/14 15:00:36:322 BST] 00000028 CMLogger      E   OutputStream encountered error during write
[12/09/14 15:00:36:322 BST] 00000028 CMLogger      E   CRVSV0960I Caused by:

Comment: Don't see ccweb.conf file in the server too

Comment: directory C:\Program Files\ibm\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\var\cache\ClearCase_check got permission for all the users.